# Integration test case using JUnit5 is not working for get request having curly braces in the URL

Tags: java, integration-testing, junit5

Integration test case using JUnit5 is not working for get request having curly braces in the URL. I am getting below error message.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'vin'

Below are the working get URL.

http://localhost:8080/test/%7Bvin%7D?coverageCode1=bca
http://localhost:8080/test/{vin}?coverageCode1=bca

Below is my controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class TestController {

@Autowired
private TestService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{vin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMessage(@RequestParam(value = "coverageCode1",
        required = false) String coverageCode1) {
    System.out.println(coverageCode1);
    return service.getMessage();
}
}
```

Below is the Integration class

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HttpRequestTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void greetingShouldReturnMessageFromService() throws Exception {
    URI url = URI.create("/test/" + URLEncoder.encode("{vin}", "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(url);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get(url)
        .param("coverageCode1", "gdc"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("SUCCESS")));
}

}
```

Below is the pom.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo_rolling_file_apender</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <mockito.version>2.24.0</mockito.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mockito + junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: don't see a controller class. It's also not clear what actual url your test is using

Comment: @Stultuske I updated the class

Comment: You indeed *don't* specify a value for the path parameter in the test, so that shouldn't be surprising. But also it's unused, so what's the point of it?

Comment: I need to pass coverageCode1 to service. That I will do later.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to the configuration. I added below annotation in the test case class file and it works.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```